# Python - exec(expression, globals=None, locals=None)

Tags: python, python-3.x, eval, standard-library

I understand the basic use of eval as shown as an example in the Python standard library:

```
x = 1
print(eval('x+1'))
2
```

Could someone please provide a more concise explanation with examples for the utilisation of both the globals and locals arguements.

Comment: amended question, good spot.

Comment: In general, do not use either `exec` or `eval` unless you absolutely know what you're doing and are certain that using it is the best possible way to solve your problem. `exec` and `eval` should usually be avoided at all costs because they introduce a multitude of problems: They're nigh-unsolvable security hazards when used on user input, can slow your code down considerably (as `exec` can manipulate locals, it actively turns off optimizations for local variables in the scope where it's used), introduce hard to find bugs, are a hassle to refactor, reduce readability, etc, etc, etc...

Answer (score 2):

If you specify global, local namespace, they are used for global, local variables instead of current scope.

```
>>> x = 1
>>> d = {'x': 9}
>>> exec('x += 1; print(x)', d, d) # x => 9 (not 1)
10
```

NOTE: `x` outside the dictionary is not affected.

```
>>> x
1
>>> d['x']
10
```

Answer (score 2):

`globals` and `locals` allow you to define the scope in which `eval` should operate, i.e. which variables should be available to it when attempting to evaluate the expression. For example:

```
>>> eval("x * 2", {'x': 5, 'y': 6}, {'x': 4})
8
```

Note that with `x` in local *and* global scope, the local version is used.